# Discord JDA onGuildMemberJoin not working

Tags: java, server, discord

I have this code:

```
public class Main extends ListenerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("MyToken")
                    .addEventListeners(new Main()).build();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event)
    {
        User user = event.getUser();
        TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("myChannelId");
        textChannel.sendMessage(String.format("%s %s", "Welcome, ", user.getName())).queue();
    }

}
```

I think this should working? I just want the bot to say "Welcome" in a specific channel when a member join the server but nothing append when I run that and join my server.

Any solutions?

Comment: when i do sysout, it go in the main but not in the onGuildMemberJoin

Comment: resolved by adding "builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS);" before building.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Discord API Join Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798536/java-discord-api-join-event)